# How to select rows which has one different value and multiple duplicate value?

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have a table like this:

```
// mytable
+----+--------------------------+---------------+-----------------+
| id |          Email           |       IP      |     cookies     |
+----+--------------------------+---------------+-----------------+
| 1  | jack.123@gmail.com       | 172.95.65.7   |  5c6ffbdd40d95  |
| 2  | ali.mngvv@yahoo.com      | 84.15.2.4     |  26b73a21e63c3  |
| 3  | redhat1931@gmail.com     | 124.54.32.1   |  e0e904b73a2fe  |
| 4  | peter_1998@gmail.com     | 172.95.65.7   |  5c6ffbdd40d95  |
| 5  | b.batman@ymail.com       | 56.23.41.3    |  b23a51a63edf4  |
| 6  | ali.mngvv@yahoo.com      | 84.15.2.4     |  26b73a21e63c3  |
+----+--------------------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

Now I want to select both first and fourth rows. Because they have identical `IP`, identical `Cookies` and different `Email`. How can I just select them?

I want this **output:**

```
// newmytable
+----+--------------------------+---------------+-----------------+
| id |          Email           |       IP      |     cookies     |
+----+--------------------------+---------------+-----------------+
| 1  | jack.123@gmail.com       | 172.95.65.7   |  5c6ffbdd40d95  |
| 4  | peter_1998@gmail.com     | 172.95.65.7   |  5c6ffbdd40d95  |
+----+--------------------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: how to know Identical?

Comment: @GoudaElalfy Whaat? Because they are the same. `172.95.65.7` and `172.95.65.7` are identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exists` as

```
select m1.* from mytable m1
where exists (
  select 1 from mytable m2
  where 
  m1.Email <> m2.Email
  and m1.IP = m2.IP
  and m1.cookies = m2.cookies
)
```

Comment: Very good +1. Just one thing, Can I use `IN` instead of `EXISTS` ?

Comment: Well exits is preferable for optimization https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subquery-optimization-with-exists.html for large dataset `exits` definitely performs better having right indexes on the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will help you

```
 SELECT id, Email,IP, cookies, COUNT(*) FROM mytable GROUP BY IP, cookies HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution without using sub queries, basically another way of querying.

```
SELECT m1.*
FROM mytable m1,mytable m2
WHERE (m1.`Email`<> m2.`Email`) AND (m1.`IP`=m2.`IP`) AND (m1.`cookies`=m2.`cookies`);
```